# Create a dataframe from dictionary - python

Tags: python, dictionary, pandas, dataframe

Say, I have a dictionary of form:

```
dct = {'A': [1,2,3], 'B': [4,5,6,7]}
```

How can it be transformed into pandas dataframe such the result will be of the form:

```
Column1  Column2
A        1
A        2
A        3
B        4
B        5
B        6
B        7
```

Comment: are those two different columns?

Comment: yes @AnandSKumar , apparently i don't know how to create a table, sorry for that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from itertools import chain
pd.DataFrame(list(chain.from_iterable(
    ((k, v) for v in vals) for (k, vals) in dct.items())),
    columns=('Column1', 'Column2'))
```

Comment: thanks, the code works, it is more general, I forgot that every value in dictionary have different lengths.

Comment: I suspected it may be the case and I am glad it works for you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `DataFrame.from_dict` to import the data:

```
In [1059]: dct = {'A': [1,2,3], 'B': [4,5,6]}

In [1060]: df = pnd.DataFrame.from_dict(dct)

In [1061]: df
Out[1061]: 
   A  B
0  1  4
1  2  5
2  3  6
```

And then simply use pandas' very handy`melt` function to unpivot the dataframe:

```
In [1062]: pnd.melt(df)
Out[1062]: 
 variable  value
0        A      1
1        A      2
2        A      3
3        B      4
4        B      5
5        B      6
```